# App crashes after splash screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Brand new to android development and I wanted to test some new code that I was working on. So I launched the my app on the emulator and the splash screen loads fine.However after the 5 second timer finishes the app crashes.

This is my Manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.PackageName.alarmclock"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.PackageName.AlarmClock.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.PackageName.AlarmClock.ASDF" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.PackageName.AlarmClock.TextPlay" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Email"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.PackageName.AlarmClock.Email" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Camera"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.PackageName.AlarmClock.Camera" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here is my splash.java

**OnCreate is dashed out in eclipse and I don't know why and if that is the reason for the crashing**

```
package com.PackageName.alarmclock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

    MediaPlayer ourSong;

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.PackageName.AlarmClock.MENU");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);
                }

            }
        };

        timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
        }
}
```

And if you need it, here is the Menu.Java

```
package com.PackageName.alarmclock;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{


    String classes[] = { "MainActivity", "TextPlay", "Splash", "Email", "Camera", "example5", "example6"};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String cheese= classes[position];

        try{
        Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.PackageName.AlarmClock." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

And here is the LogCat

```
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-84
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): Process: com.PackageName.alarmclock, PID: 1985
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.PackageName.AlarmClock.MENU }
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
07-16 00:48:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.PackageName.alarmclock.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:28)
```

Any help is appreciated as I've spent pretty much the whole day on this app and It'd suck to lose it.

Comment: delete `gen` and `bin` folders and try again. You gave wrong package name `com.PackageName.AlarmClock` instead give `com.PackageName.alarmclock` in every `class` where ever you gave `com.PackageName.AlarmClock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Call it in Intent as :

```
 Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class);
```

Right now what you have in your manifest is:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

which, from the code that you have pasted, doesn't exist.

Leave alone, the `ListActivity` in java file has the name "Menu" and what you declared in manifest is "MENU"

Comment: glad to solve the problem, welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. You will [prevent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) a [conundrum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use intents something like this

```
Intent i=new Intent(Firstactivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Where first activity is your current activity and second activity is the one you want to move on to; but in your finally block you are doing something like

```
 Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.PackageName.AlarmClock.MENU");//wrong
 //you specified only one argument


startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in `Splash.java` file

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.PackageName.AlarmClock.MENU");
```

to

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent();
openMainActivity.setClass(this, Menu.class);
```

And

in `Menu.java file` change from

```
Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.PackageName.AlarmClock." + cheese);
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

to

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent();
ourIntent.setClass(this, AlarmClock.class);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```